Find game with Yulaw character
I had some time ago a PS1 or PS2 with a fighting game. There was the character Yulaw. Also Nina was there. I checked several websites and Wikipedia lists. I would think the game I had was Street Fighter or Tekken. I remember the phrase "Yulaw wins". (Yes, and it has nothing to do with "The One")


Out of curiosity, where did you find that image? For context, I ran a Google Image search of that image and found an exact match confirming that the image is from Tekken 3: https://tekken.fandom.com/fr/wiki/Nina_Williams/Galerie_vid%C3%A9o#Tekken_3

The game is Tekken 3 for PS1.
The character from the image is the one you mentioned, Nina Williams.
The other one you remember is actually called Forest Law.

Yes, there was no tag for PS1 (or I missed it), and I don't remember which one I had. I know it's Nina. And after looking at some more pictures from a tekken search, I remembered what happened. The character was Law. And funnily enough, it had to do with the movie "The One". I just liked Yulaw better than Law.

You might want to mention that one of the characters is called "Law". As things stand, it's not entirely clear why this answer is the correct one based on the question.
